# Parsing xml and dump in file each <> block

Tags: c++, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml with some simple C++  which has blocks like

```
 <mgrwt event="1">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </mgrwt>

<mgrwt event="2">
    ...
    ...
    ...
 </mgrwt>
```

Now, I have a bash script which acts on each of these blocks - So, my question is,  how can I loop inside the xml ( I do not need RapidXML or something similar though) so that to easily dump to a small temp file each   block ?

My parser looks like

```
  bool begin_tag = false;
    while (getline(in,line))
    {
        std::string tmp; 
        tmp=line;
       if(line.find("<mgrwt event=")<=line.size()){
            cout<<line<<endl;
            begin_tag = true;
            continue;
        }
        else if (tmp == "</mgrwt>")
        {
            begin_tag = false;

        }

     }
}
```

thanks

Alex

Comment: yeah, actually tmp = line ; thanks

Comment: If the file is XML, I would suggest using an XML parser. Anything else will end up causing problems down the line. If you are really intent on **not** using an XML parser, how about using a different file format? Most scripting/programming languages work wonderfully with simple line-based parameter files or CSVs.

Comment: still...can please someone help me how to read one block each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an XML parser for reading XML files. Checkout [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), [POCO XML](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) or other libraries.

If you can't for whatever reason, and the stuff you're reading always looks exactly the same as in your sample with no other formatting variations, you also should use `find()` to detect the end of the block:

```
else if(line.find("</mgrwt>")<=line.size())
{
   begin_tag = false;
}
```

Comment: hi...Actually XML is not an option for me...So, actually, the question is how to print the lines between arguments, using C++....